# Login IF statement , the else always getting displayed, possible wrong written script

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

**I always get the "else", even though I add the correct username and password**
[Photo with the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMmvt.png)

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CONSTRing);
    con.Open();
    string q = "select * from LOGG where username = '" + tbu.Text + "' and password = '" + tbp.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
    SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
    Da.Fill(DT);
    if (DT.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        Form Main = new Form();
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + tbu.Text);
        this.Hide();
        Main.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Check your Username and Password");
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

[Photo with dbo.LOGG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcv9M.png)

Comment: First and foremost - **[USE PARAMETERISED QUERIES](https://bobby-tables.com/)** - Apologies for the all caps,but I can't stress this enough. Your current design is a massive security risk - especially since you are storing your passwords as plain text (which is also a big no no). To actually answer your question though, it is hard to say exactly why your data table does not have one row. Have you tried debugging and stepping through the code? As an aside, why would your password field be nullable?

Comment: You may also wish to read up on [some coding conventions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/csharp-style.html), or at the very least use constant casing across your code. You have `CONSTRing`, `Da`, `cmd`, and `Dt` all in the same very small code block - while intellisense will assist with making sure you don't have issues referencing things, making your names consistent will massively improve the readability of your code.

Comment: its for a school project, i know this isn t secure, i dont focus on security for now

Comment: Security and code style aside, the best way to figure this out will be to debug and step through your code and inspect the variable `q` before it is executed, then run the SQL against the DB directly to see if that returns any results. If that does return results, then you should check your connection string to ensure you are executing against the correct database

Comment: Parameterising your queries is about more than just security, it is about type safety, sanitised inputs, and plan reuse. For example, if a username has an apostrophe in it, you are going to get malformed SQL. It is minimal effort to implement parameterised queries, and it is a good habit to get into regardless of the size or scope of your project

Comment: @GarethD Exactly the point I often make on here when someone says "oh it's just a school project" or "oh the inputs aren't user-defined". Data and code should remain separate. No-one would *dream* of writing C# with embedded data and compiling it dynamically, one should treat SQL the same way.

Comment: There are other issues with this code (won't fix the main problem but should be changed): connection, command and adapter need `using` blocks to dispose them. Why `select *` if you just want to know if a row exists? Instead do `select 1` then remove the adapter and just use `if((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1)`

Comment: Aside from all the good comments above.  Simple answer is that the "LOGG" table must contain multiple records with the same username and password...

Answer (score 1):

I will try to be helpful with an answer since I can't yet comment ;_;
Below is some code I compiled as an improvement to the one you posted.

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();
            string q = "select 1 from LOGG where username = @username and password = @password";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", tbu.Text); //
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", tbp.Text); // using parameters to avoid intentional or accidental SqlInjection by the user

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Form Main = new Form();
                        MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + tbu.Text);
                        this.Hide();
                        Main.Show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Check your Username and Password");
                    }
                    con.Close();

                    cmd.Dispose();
                    con.Dispose();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Oops something went wrong. Error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

This is how I would write a quick version of what you wanted. Now, it might not help you out with your issue but it fixes some of the more obvious issues that might come up.

The Try and Catch block are there just for basic error handling to let the user know something went wrong.
The SqlDataReader is enough to notify you if a user with the given parameters exists in the database.

The check you used before

```cs
if (Dt.Rows.Count == 1)
   {
    //...
   }
```

would fail to trigger if your query returned more than 1 row, which should not happen if the Table is created correctly. Check for duplicate entries in your table.